# AFNetworking GET does not finish while app in background

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking

I am trying to achieve this:

1) A silent push notification is received by my app to inform it that there is new data to download via background transfer service, i.e. content-available = 1

2) The app is launched in the background, then runs a GET command to my server to determine the URL of the new file to download

3) The app downloads this file via background transfer service

I have this working fine when the app is running.  It requires two AFHTTPSessionManager objects.  Step #2 requires one that is initialized in default NSURLSessionConfiguration because the GET function uses a data task, which is not supported while in background NSURLSessionConfiguration (see limitations [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html)).  Step #3 requires one that is in background NSURLSessionConfiguration.

However, when I launch the app in the debugger by running the push notification, the GET call never calls the success or failure blocks.  I am going to Debug --> Attach to Process, then entering my process name.  Then Xcode goes from 'waiting for launch' state to 'attached to process' state when I send the push notification.  I can use breakpoints to see that the AFHTTPSessionManager is being created properly, and the GET:parameters:success:failure function is being called.  However, the breakpoints in the success/failure blocks never get called.

Am I able to run a non-background-configured session manager while the app is in background state?  If not, how am I supposed to get download info from my server while in background state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the app was entering suspended state before the GET response could come back from the server and the success/failure blocks could be called.

I had to follow the process [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28) under "Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background".  Essentially, I needed to call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: on the application before making the GET call so that the OS knew not to suspend my app immediately.

Everything else was just a big mess of red herrings!

Comment: Is `Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background' continue working even if `background app refresh` turned off by the user?